# Super increasing knapsack encryption programme

Tags: encryption, knapsack

Im creating a super increasing knapsack encryption scheme. Im supposed to ask the user to key in the size of the super-increasing knapsack. My question is - is there a minimum number of elements that the user need to key in?

Based on my research, because ASCII is using 7bit encoding, I need to have at least 8 elements. I would like to understand why this is? or is it correct at all?

Thank you.

Comment: I am currently unable to see how this is on-topic.  Your "_need to have at least 8 elements_" remark does not seem sensible. Cite your reference, please. Edit the original question to clarify. If there is a technical argument you wish to make, then make it, by revising the question. As stated it is hard to determine what you intend.

Comment: @J_H: I think he is intending to use knapsack to encrypt individual ASCII characters.  <sarcasm=MAX>I can't imagine what could go wrong with that</sarcasm>